# Auto_ Arima model not predicting as expected

Tags: nan, arima

I have the auto_arima model that helps me predict the volume weighted average of stock prices, I have split the data into train & test data, however the model isn't predicting as expected, it produces just one value for the predicted value, and when I try to append it to my data frame, I get nan. Could I be doing something wrong? Please see my code below

from pmdarima import auto_arima
model=auto_arima(y=train_data['VWAP'], exogenous=train_data[ind_features],trace=True)
model.fit(train_data['VWAP'])
model.predict(n_periods=len(test_data),exogenous= test_data[ind_features])

(**"""The image attached is what i get after this line"""")**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXda9.png)

I have tried removing the exogenous component from the fit model & added it back but that doesn't change the results.